# How to take input from file in Oracle and update the Oracle database table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to update the database in oracle by taking input from file.Means I have some input fields in file  and update the table by taking that input.

Can I do this by creating directory and using utl_file which is provided in Oracle.

Comment: Yes.  But utl_file can only open files in directories known to the oracle database as directory objects.

Comment: Oracle has provided [External Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#g1017623) for this kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a `DIRECTORY` object and then use `UTL_FILE` or something similar to open and read the file, then `INSERT` into your table. I can't be more specific since you didn't really tell us anything about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the SQL*Loader or import utilities would work for you too:
SQL*Loader: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706
import: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#g1025464